# Spring 3.1 ViewResolver for local content (swf object)

Tags: java, spring, url-mapping

In my project my jsp form contains a swf object which is placed in "WEB-INF/fl". When I publish project I am getting "url mapping not found" error for swf object. How can I make my local content available?

My ViewResolver Bean:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.udb.common.controllers" />

<bean 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController{


    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap map, Principal principal){

        String name = principal.getName();
        map.addAttribute("username", name);
        map.addAttribute("message", "Spring Security Custom Form Exmple");


        return "hello";

    }
```

But when I publish project on server I am getting below error:

```
Dec 30, 2011 3:49:29 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/security/param.swf] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve static content using the tag

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/security/**" location="/fl/" />
```

Comment: Thank you, after spending some time I have also included <mvc:annotation-driven /> and it works!